# Split word + pattern from column in pandas dataset

Tags: python, pandas, data-cleaning

I have a column in pandas dataframe like this:

| total |
| --- |
| tapasn17 , porton34 , rivern55 |
| waitedn345 , dishn1 , saladn54 ,winen9 |
| 0 |
| 0 |

I would like to remove the **n *number*** from this column so it looks like this

| total |
| --- |
| tapas , porto , river |
| waited , dish , salad ,wine |
| 0 |
| 0 |

I tried like this but only gives me the first word and still with the *n* at the end

```
rt = r'^(?P<total>[A-Za-z]+)'
df['total'].str.extract(rt)
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Try `str.replace`:

```
df['total'] = df['total'].str.replace('(n\d+)', '')
```

Output:

```
                         total
0        tapas , porto , river
1  waited , dish , salad ,wine
2                            0
3                            0
```

Comment: Why would you use `df.str.replace` instead of `df.replace`?

Comment: @MitchellOlislagers `str.replace` works with regex by default.